# Como transformar vários JSON num só JSON válido com json_encode no PHP

Tags: php, json

Olá! Possuo um script que ao final de cada laço while imprime um json

```
echo json_encode($retorno);
```

O resultado ao rodar o script é (exemplo trazendo vários resultados)

```
    {
    "IdClienteLS": 1695,
    "Nome": "Magia das Flores",
    "Anuncio": "",
    "Telefones": [{
        "Wpp": 0,
        "Fone": "(49) 3224-0196"
    }],
    "Email": "",
    "RedeSocial": "",
    "Site": "",
    "PalavrasChave": ["", null],
    "Ramos": ["Floriculturas"],
    "Logradouro": "",
    "Bairro": "",
    "Cidade": "Lages",
    "Cep": "",
    "Estado": "SC",
    "Complemento": "",
    "Latitude": "",
    "Longitude": ""
} {
    "IdClienteLS": 20141,
    "Nome": "BF Motos",
    "Anuncio": "",
    "Telefones": [{
        "Wpp": 0,
        "Fone": "(49) 3225-5497"
    }],
    "Email": "",
    "RedeSocial": "",
    "Site": "",
    "PalavrasChave": ["", null],
    "Ramos": ["Motos"],
    "Logradouro": "",
    "Bairro": "",
    "Cidade": "Lages",
    "Cep": "",
    "Estado": "SC",
    "Complemento": "",
    "Latitude": "",
    "Longitude": ""
} {
    "IdClienteLS": 3656,
    "Nome": "Trateq",
    "Anuncio": "",
    "Telefones": [],
    "Email": "",
    "RedeSocial": "",
    "Site": "",
    "PalavrasChave": ["", null],
    "Ramos": ["Motos"],
    "Logradouro": "",
    "Bairro": "",
    "Cidade": "",
    "Cep": "",
    "Estado": "",
    "Complemento": "",
    "Latitude": "",
    "Longitude": ""
} {
    "IdClienteLS": 10874,
    "Nome": "Jeane Karine Marcon - Consultora de Beleza",
    "Anuncio": "",
    "Telefones": [],
    "Email": "",
    "RedeSocial": "",
    "Site": "",
    "PalavrasChave": ["", null],
    "Ramos": ["Motos"],
    "Logradouro": "",
    "Bairro": "",
    "Cidade": "",
    "Cep": "",
    "Estado": "",
    "Complemento": "",
    "Latitude": "",
    "Longitude": ""
} {
    "IdClienteLS": 25713,
    "Nome": "Dalia Festas e Eventos",
    "Anuncio": "",
    "Telefones": [],
    "Email": "",
    "RedeSocial": "",
    "Site": "",
    "PalavrasChave": ["", null],
    "Ramos": ["Eventos", "Festas"],
    "Logradouro": "",
    "Bairro": "",
    "Cidade": "",
    "Cep": "",
    "Estado": "",
    "Complemento": "",
    "Latitude": "",
    "Longitude": ""
}
```

O resultado completo não é um JSON válido (testei no [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/)). Isso por se tratar da impressão de vários, um seguida do outro. Pra corrigir, eu tentei montar outro array assim:

```
$retornoScript[] = $retorno;
```

E depois de acabar o laço while dei encode no array $retornoScript contendo todos os outros, assim:

```
echo json_encode($retornoScript);
```

Mas o script não roda apresenta nada. Nem erro nem informação. Alguém sabe me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado? O script foi solicitado por terceiro, então o propósito é esse mesmo: retornar (depois de ler alguns parâmetros) informações do banco de dados num JSON.

Código PHP para verificação:

```
$buscaClientes = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE status = 1 AND data_alteracao BETWEEN date('{$dataSQL}') AND date('{$dataHJ}') LIMIT {$inicio}, {$fim}");

if(mysqli_num_rows($buscaClientes) != 0){
        //$retornoScript = array();

        while($dadosCliente = mysqli_fetch_array($buscaClientes)){
            //Busca Atividades
            //Verifica se vem da integração ou da importacao
            if($dadosCliente['integracao'] == 1){
                //Busca Atividades
                $sqlAtividadesCliente = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT cc.id_cliente, cat.nome AS nome_categoria, cat.url FROM categorias cat INNER JOIN cliente_categorias cc ON cat.id_sistema_ls = cc.id_categoria AND cat.status = 1 INNER JOIN clientes cli ON cli.id_ls = cc.id_cliente AND cli.status = 1 AND cli.id_ls = {$dadosCliente['id_ls']} GROUP BY nome_categoria");
            }else{
                //Busca Atividades
                $sqlAtividadesCliente = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT cc.id_cliente, cat.nome AS nome_categoria, cat.url FROM categorias cat INNER JOIN cliente_categorias cc ON cat.id_ls = cc.id_categoria AND cat.status = 1 INNER JOIN clientes cli ON cli.id_ls = cc.id_cliente AND cli.status = 1 AND cli.id_ls = {$dadosCliente['id_ls']} GROUP BY nome_categoria");
            }

            $countAtividades = mysqli_num_rows($sqlAtividadesCliente);

            //Endereços do Cliente
            $sqlEnderecosCliente = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM endereco_cliente WHERE id_cliente = {$dadosCliente['id']}");

            //Telefones do Cliente
            $sqlTelefonesCliente   = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM telefone_cliente WHERE id_cliente = {$dadosCliente['id']}");


            //Endereço Mapa
            $sqlEndereco = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM endereco_cliente WHERE id_cliente = {$dadosCliente['id']} ORDER BY id_ls ASC LIMIT 1");
            $dadosEndereco = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlEndereco);

            //PalavrasChave
            $palavras    = $dadosCliente['palavras_chave'];
            $palavra     = explode(",", $palavras);
            $numPalavras = count($palavra);

            //Palavras Chave para o Google
            $palavrasChave = array();
            for ($i = 0; $i <= $numPalavras; $i++) {
                $palavrasChave[] = $palavra[$i];
            }

            $telefones = array();
            while($dadosFone = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlTelefonesCliente)){
                    $telefones[] = array("Wpp" => (int) $dadosFone['whatsapp'], "Fone" => $dadosFone['telefone']);
            }

            //Atividades
            if($countAtividades != 0){
                    $ramos = array();
                    while($dadosAtividade = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlAtividadesCliente)){
                        $ramos[] = $dadosAtividade['nome_categoria'];
                    }
            }

            //Retorna Array jSON
            $retorno = array("IdClienteLS"    => (int) $dadosCliente['id_ls'], 
                            "Nome"        => $dadosCliente['nome'], 
                            "Anuncio"     => $dadosCliente['imagem'],
                            "Telefones"   => $telefones,
                            "Email"       => $dadosCliente['email'],
                            "RedeSocial"  => $dadosCliente['redesocial'],
                            "Site"        => $dadosCliente['site'],
                            "PalavrasChave" => $palavrasChave,
                            "Ramos"       => $ramos,
                            "Logradouro"  => trim($dadosEndereco['logradouro']),
                            "Bairro"      => trim($dadosEndereco['bairro']),
                            "Cidade"      => trim($dadosEndereco['cidade']),
                            "Cep"         => trim($dadosEndereco['cep']),
                            "Estado"      => trim($dadosEndereco['estado']),
                            "Complemento" => trim($dadosEndereco['complemento']),
                            "Latitude"    => $dadosCliente['longitude'],
                            "Longitude"   => $dadosCliente['altitude']
                            );

                    //$retornoScript[] = $retorno;
                    echo json_encode($retorno);
                }
}
```

Comment: A princípio, o que fez deveria funcionar, mas seria melhor você [edit] a pergunta e adicionar o código PHP para afirmarmos exatamente o que está aocntecendo.

Comment: O correto é `$retornoScript[] = $retorno;`, mas é necessário saber como esses dados estão sendo processados, só assim saberemos o porque o *script* não apresenta nada.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Obrigada, Anderson. Adicionei :)

Comment: @ValdeirPsr Obrigada, Valdeir. Adicionei :)

Comment: Já tentou  json_encode($retorno, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT); ?

Comment: Oi @ChristianLuãLemos! Obrigada por contribuir, mas também não funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O bug era por causa do charset :( bobeira haha. Ao dar um var_dump notei que o charset estava com problemas. Corrigindo ele, o json compilou. Obrigada!

Apenas para demonstração, adicionei o charset na conexão

```
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
```

E no encode do json fiz

```
echo json_encode($retornoScript, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

A declaração da variável $ramos no seu código pode ser indefinida dependendo do resultado da execução, gerando um possível erro, tirando isso o código parece estar ok.
Editei seu código adicionando uma variável $dados que recebe o conteúdo a ser transformado para json, e mudei o local de declaração da variável $ramos, e no final de tudo o json_encode($dados) onde caso a mesma seja vazia irá imprimir um json "[]" e caso contrário o conteúdo atribuído. Espero que ajude!

```
$buscaClientes = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE status = 1 AND data_alteracao BETWEEN date('{$dataSQL}') AND date('{$dataHJ}') LIMIT {$inicio}, {$fim}");
$dados = [];

if(mysqli_num_rows($buscaClientes) != 0){
    //$retornoScript = array();

    while($dadosCliente = mysqli_fetch_array($buscaClientes)){
        //Busca Atividades
        //Verifica se vem da integração ou da importacao
        if($dadosCliente['integracao'] == 1){
            //Busca Atividades
            $sqlAtividadesCliente = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT cc.id_cliente, cat.nome AS nome_categoria, cat.url FROM categorias cat INNER JOIN cliente_categorias cc ON cat.id_sistema_ls = cc.id_categoria AND cat.status = 1 INNER JOIN clientes cli ON cli.id_ls = cc.id_cliente AND cli.status = 1 AND cli.id_ls = {$dadosCliente['id_ls']} GROUP BY nome_categoria");
        }else{
            //Busca Atividades
            $sqlAtividadesCliente = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT cc.id_cliente, cat.nome AS nome_categoria, cat.url FROM categorias cat INNER JOIN cliente_categorias cc ON cat.id_ls = cc.id_categoria AND cat.status = 1 INNER JOIN clientes cli ON cli.id_ls = cc.id_cliente AND cli.status = 1 AND cli.id_ls = {$dadosCliente['id_ls']} GROUP BY nome_categoria");
        }

        $countAtividades = mysqli_num_rows($sqlAtividadesCliente);

        //Endereços do Cliente
        $sqlEnderecosCliente = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM endereco_cliente WHERE id_cliente = {$dadosCliente['id']}");

        //Telefones do Cliente
        $sqlTelefonesCliente   = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM telefone_cliente WHERE id_cliente = {$dadosCliente['id']}");


        //Endereço Mapa
        $sqlEndereco = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM endereco_cliente WHERE id_cliente = {$dadosCliente['id']} ORDER BY id_ls ASC LIMIT 1");
        $dadosEndereco = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlEndereco);

        //PalavrasChave
        $palavras    = $dadosCliente['palavras_chave'];
        $palavra     = explode(",", $palavras);
        $numPalavras = count($palavra);

        //Palavras Chave para o Google
        $palavrasChave = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i <= $numPalavras; $i++) {
            $palavrasChave[] = $palavra[$i];
        }

        $telefones = array();
        while($dadosFone = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlTelefonesCliente)){
            $telefones[] = array("Wpp" => (int) $dadosFone['whatsapp'], "Fone" => $dadosFone['telefone']);
        }

        //Atividades
        $ramos = array();
        if($countAtividades != 0){

            while($dadosAtividade = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlAtividadesCliente)){
                $ramos[] = $dadosAtividade['nome_categoria'];
            }
        }

        //Retorna Array jSON
        $retorno = array("IdClienteLS"    => (int) $dadosCliente['id_ls'],
            "Nome"        => $dadosCliente['nome'],
            "Anuncio"     => $dadosCliente['imagem'],
            "Telefones"   => $telefones,
            "Email"       => $dadosCliente['email'],
            "RedeSocial"  => $dadosCliente['redesocial'],
            "Site"        => $dadosCliente['site'],
            "PalavrasChave" => $palavrasChave,
            "Ramos"       => $ramos,
            "Logradouro"  => trim($dadosEndereco['logradouro']),
            "Bairro"      => trim($dadosEndereco['bairro']),
            "Cidade"      => trim($dadosEndereco['cidade']),
            "Cep"         => trim($dadosEndereco['cep']),
            "Estado"      => trim($dadosEndereco['estado']),
            "Complemento" => trim($dadosEndereco['complemento']),
            "Latitude"    => $dadosCliente['longitude'],
            "Longitude"   => $dadosCliente['altitude']
        );

        $dados[] = $retorno;
    }
}

echo json_encode($dados);
```

Comment: Oi Bruno! Valeu pela ajuda mas nada mudou :( até declarei outro valor pra $ramos pra teste, mas nada aconteceu. Será que não existe nenhuma limitação no JSON pelo fato de ser um "array, com um array dentro, com outros arrays...", um array multidimensional?

Comment: Limitação por ser multidimensional não existe não, o fator mais provável é que tenha algum erro no código mesmo. Tente habilitar o output de erros do PHP para ver se algo é mostrado.